# Correcting space on title

Tags: spacing

This question is a continuation of [Renaming default chapter text in tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394742/renaming-default-chapter-text-in-tcolorbox):

To control the spacing of this region:

[image]

Should I simply add information after `\documentclass{book}` or add information after `\titleformat`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\definecolor{titlebgdark}{RGB}{219,17,28}
\definecolor{titlebglight}{RGB}{51,41,241}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{}
{10pt}
{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        colback=titlebgdark,
        boxrule=0.25cm,
        colframe=titlebglight,
        arc=0pt,
        outer arc=0pt,
        leftrule=0pt,
        rightrule=0pt,
        fontupper=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\huge,
        enlarge left by=-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin, 
        enlarge right by=-\paperwidth+1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth,
        width=\paperwidth, 
        left=1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin, 
        right=\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth,
        top=0.6cm, 
        bottom=0.6cm,
        overlay={
            \node[
            fill=titlebgdark,
            draw=titlebglight,
            line width=0.15cm,
            inner sep=0pt,
            text width=1.7cm,
            minimum height=1.7cm,
            align=center,
            font=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont
            ] 
            (chapname)
            at ([xshift=-4cm]frame.north east)
            {\thechapter};
            \node[font=\small,anchor=south,inner sep=2pt] at (chapname.north)
            {\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename};  
        } 
        ]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\titleformat{name=\chapter sd,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{}
{20pt}
{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        colback=titlebgdark,
        boxrule=0.25cm,
        colframe=titlebglight,
        arc=0pt,
        outer arc=0pt,
        remember as=title,
        leftrule=0pt,
        rightrule=0pt,
        fontupper=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\huge,
        enlarge left by=-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin, 
        enlarge right by=-\paperwidth+1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth,
        width=\paperwidth, 
        left=1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin, 
        right=\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth,
        top=0.6cm, 
        bottom=0.6cm, 
        ]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Prefácio}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the second argument of `\titlespacing`: for instance,

```
          \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-58pt}{40pt}
```

yields this:

[image]